# Upgrade DataStax Enterprise from DSE 5.0.7 to 5.1.2

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We are running DSE 5.0.7 in our production environment. Planning to upgrade to 5.1. Can we upgrade to DSE 5.1.2 directly or should we upgrade to 5.1.0 and then to 5.1.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to upgrade directly as the sstable format is the same between versions.